# HTML form not sending data to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am making a website and am having trouble having a form send data to PHP. Here is my code for the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="id" placeholder="placeholder">
    </div>
</div>
-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name of the Program</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="lang" class="col-sm-2 control-label">What language is it in</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select multiple class="form-control" id="lang" name="lang[]">
            <option value="java">Java</option>
            <option value="python">Python</option>
            <option value="webiste">Website(HTML, PHP, CSS or Javascript)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Hold down control to select multiple.</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="desc" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Give a description about it</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea id="desc" name="desc" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload the file</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="file" placeholder="File">
    </div>
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">If it is in multiple files put it in a ZIP file.</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Continue</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I use BootStrap for the form)
Here is my code for php:

```
<?php
$error = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) || $_POST['name'] == ''){
        $error[1] = 'Please enter the name form.';
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['lang']) || $_POST['lang'] == array()){
        $error[2] = 'Please enter the language form.';
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['desc']) || $_POST['desc'] == ''){
        $error[3] = 'Please enter the description form.';
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['file']) || $_POST['file'] == ''){
        $error[4] = 'Please select a file.';
    }
    if(isset($error) && $error != array()){
        foreach($error as $e => $k){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> ' . $k . '</div>';
        }
    }else{
        $data = array();
        $data['name'] = $db->mySQLSafe($_POST['name']);
        $data['file'] = $db->mySQLSafe(serialize($_POST['file']));
        $data['description'] = $db->mySQLSafe($_POST['desc']);
        $data['author'] = $db->mySQLSafe($result[0]['full name']);
        $data['page'] = $db->mySQLSafe('projects');

        $insert = $db->insert('projects', $data);
        if($insert){
            $target_file = 'projects/' . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $fileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            echo $target_file . '<br />';
            echo $fileType . '<br />';
            $uploadok = 1;
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> That file already exists, try a different file name.</div>';
                $uploadok = 0;
            }
            if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5000000) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> That file is too large.</div>';
                $uploadok = 0;
            }
            if($fileType != 'zip' && $fileType != 'gz' && $fileType != 'java' && $fileType != 'py' && $fileType != 'html' && $fileType != 'css' && $fileType != 'js'){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> That type of file is not acceptable.</div>';
                $uploadok = 0;
            }
            if($uploadok == 0){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> The file was not uploaded.</div>';
            }else{
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Yes!</strong> It was successfully submitted!</div>';
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"><strong>Warning!</strong> There was an error uploading your file with error code ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '.</div>';
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> There was an error inserting the data.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I am trying to have it get a file from the user and send the file to a folder, but the form is not even sending. After I added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` it just completely stop sending the data, I am not sure if that is needed or not, but it is not working.

Comment: IS the php and on the same page as the html?

Comment: Yes, the php and the html are in the same file.

Comment: You're saying that if you remove the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` the data gets sent? Can you check with developer tools(network tab) the response of the form submission?

Comment: How would I exactly use the developer tools @BardhLohaj ?

Answer (score -1):

You have no place for the form to send the data.

see:

`<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

In here, you should have something like `action="myprocessingpage.php"`, where `myprocessingpage.php` is where you're processing the post data.

It also appears that you're missing a closing `</form>` tag as well.

Comment: The action attribute is optional, forms default to submitting to the current URI. The end tag for the form element is mandatory, but leaving it out won't break anything if there are no subsequent forms.

Comment: Yes, I have the end `</form>` tag, I just forgot to include it.

Comment: It would have helped if the OP had said he was sending the data to the same URI, so thanks for that -1 on something I had no idea he was doing. :)